# Searching using RegEx

Tags: javascript, python, regex, web-scraping

I want to extract the data as follows:

Questions No. 11

Question: Find the error (if any) in the following code snippet for pop operation.
void pop() //removing an element from a stack { printf(“%s”, stack[top++]); }

Option-a: run time error 
Option-b: compile-time error 
Option-c: pop operation is performed, but top moved in the wrong direction 
Option-d: pop operation is performed properly View Answer

The regex below for some reason stops at number 9 and is not selection numbers from 10 to 12. I am not able to figure the issue

I will appreciate every help I get.

Thank you in advance

Sample data and RegEx Code [RegEx and Sample Data](https://regex101.com/r/GgtNwZ/3)

```
^(?<number>\d{1,2})\.\s(?<question>.*?)\sa\)\s(?<a>.*?)\sb\)\s(?<b>.*?)\s(?:c\)\s(?<c>.*?)\s(?:d\)(?<d>.*?)\s)?)?View Answer\s{0,3}$
```

1. Reversing a word using stack can be used to find if the given word is a palindrome or not. a) True b) False View Answer
2. Which is the most appropriate data structure for reversing a word? a) queue b) stack c) tree d) graph View Answer
3. Operations required for reversing a word or a string using stack are push() and pop(). a) True b) False View Answer
4. What is the time complexity of reversing a word using stack algorithm? a) O (N log N) b) O (N2) c) O (N) d) O (M log N) View Answer
5. What will be the word obtained if the word “abbcabb” is reversed using a stack? a) bbabbca b) abbcabb c) bbacbba d) bbacabb View Answer
6. How many stacks are required for reversing a word algorithm? a) one b) two c) three d) four View Answer
7. What will be result if the given stack is popped? a) pat b) tap c) atp d) apt View Answer
8. What will be output if the following sequence of operations are executed? Push(a,s); Push(b,s); Pop(b); Push(c,s); a) abc b) b c) ac d) acb View Answer
9. What are the set of functions that are to be executed to get the following output? cat a) push(c, s); push(a, s); push(t, s); pop(s); pop(s); pop(s); b) push(c,s); pop(s); push(a,s); pop(s);push(t,s);pop(s); c) pop(c ); pop(a); pop(t); d) push(c,s); push(a,s); pop(t); View Answer
10. How will your stack look like if the word ‘java’ is pushed? a) b) c) d) View Answer
11. Find the error (if any) in the following code snippet for pop operation.
    void pop() //removing an element from a stack { printf(“%s”, stack[top++]); }
    a) run time error b) compile time error c) pop operation is performed, but top moved in wrong direction d) pop operation is performed properly View Answer
12. What will be the output of the following program?
    main() { char str[]="san foundry"; int len = strlen(str); int i;   for(i=0;i

Comment: Always place code/strings inside your question. External links could, at any point in time, stop working. This then makes your question absolutely useless for future goers. Also, check out [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) so that you can properly markdown your question so that we can easily understand it. Right now, it's unclear what's expected output, and what's text from your question. Oh and is it python or JavaScript - two very different answers when it comes to regex (e.g. lookbehinds are only partially supported in JavaScript)?

Comment: Why not just split by newline (since none of your questions are multiline)?

Comment: Your pattern does not take 11 into account, Perhaps  try `^11\..*(?:\r?\n(?!12\.).*)*` https://regex101.com/r/GgtNwZ/1 to make it a bit more efficient.

Comment: Also `[a,b,c,d]` checks to see if any character in the set `a,bcd` exists at that location - not `abcd` - every character in a character set is checked.

Comment: place code/strings inside your question - > Done

Comment: [link] https://regex101.com/r/STecfo/5 RegEx
`^11\..*(?:\r?\n(?!12\.).*)*` This does select code but you need to hard code the numbers which are not feasible and cannot be implemented

Comment: `^(?<number>\d{1,2})\.\s(?<question>.*?)\sa\)\s(?<a>.*?)\sb\)\s(?<b>.*?)\s(?:c\)\s(?<c>.*?)\s(?:d\)(?<d>.*?)\s)?)?View Answer\s{0,3}$` https://regex101.com/r/xq12vI/3 ← this might help you get closer to what you want (it is a not-fully-accomplishing-what-you-want PCRE(PHP) v1 regex, failing with some stuff)

Comment: Yes, its something close but unfortunately it skips anything after question 9 and when selecting, it selects everything together which kills the purpose of having questions separate from options.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: [This one](https://regex101.com/r/qAmiVi/4) gets you everything you want, I think--in separate capturing groups for Question Number, Question Text, and "View Answer", so you could replace them (e.g., with group backreferences) or discard them at will:

```
const regex = /(\d{1,2}\. )|(?<=\d{1,2}\. ).*?(?=View Answer)|View Answer/gms;
```

[This regex works](https://regex101.com/r/qAmiVi/2) if you don't mind not matching "View Answer" -- I saved the unit tests in Regex101, too.

```
const regex = /\d{1,2}.*?(?=View Answer)/gms;

const str = `9. What are the set of functions that are to be executed to get the following output? cat a) push(c, s); push(a, s); push(t, s); pop(s); pop(s); pop(s); b) push(c,s); pop(s); push(a,s); pop(s);push(t,s);pop(s); c) pop(c ); pop(a); pop(t); d) push(c,s); push(a,s); pop(t); View Answer
10. How will your stack look like if the word ‘java’ is pushed? a) b) c) d) View Answer
11. Find the error (if any) in the following code snippet for pop operation.
void pop() //removing an element from a stack { printf(“%s”, stack[top++]); }
a) run time error b) compile time error c) pop operation is performed, but top moved in wrong direction d) pop operation is performed properly View Answer
12. What will be the output of the following program?
main() { char str[]="san foundry"; int len = strlen(str); int i;   for(i=0;i<len;i++) push(str[i]); // pushes an element into stack   for(i=0;i<len;i++) pop(); //pops an element from the stack }
a) sanfoundry b) san foundry c) yrdnuof nas d) foundry nas View Answer
Sanfoundry Global Education & Learning Series – Data Structure.
To practice all areas of Data Structure, here is complete set of 1000+ Multiple Choice Questions and Answers.`;

let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {

    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that for **question 10** there are no answers following a) b) etc.. If you want to allow those as well, you could make the answers optional using `a\)\s(?<a>.*?\s)?` and move the whitespace inside the optional group to prevent having to match 2 whitespace chars.

The issue in **question 11** is that `void pop() //removing an element from a stack { printf(“%s”, stack[top++]); }` is on a new line.

To fix it you could add an optional non capturing group `(?:\r?\n.*)?` to match a second line if there is one.

To match all the lines and groups, your pattern might look like:

```
^(?<number>\d{1,2})\.\s(?<question>.*?(?:\r?\n.*)?)\sa\)\s(?<a>.*?\s)?b\)\s(?<b>.*?\s)?c\)\s(?<c>.*?\s)?d\)(?<d>.*?\s)?View Answer\s{0,3}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IpT7nF/1)

Comment: This code is indeed selecting everything and it the only functional code when selecting everything. The problem is when I just need to select only the questions skipping everything else.

Questions selection should be : **Find the error (if any) in the following code snippet for pop operation. void pop() //removing an element from a stack { printf(“%s”, stack[top++]); }**

Comment: @ИΛβΞΞĿҜHΛИ In that case you could make something specific to find in the question if you don't want to use the numbers. Try it like this https://regex101.com/r/67e4w2/1